# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions

Tags: java, selenium, jakarta-ee, guava

Im getting this error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:339)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
```

Im building a bot for social media , so Im using Selenium libraries, and the bot works fine on a Java Application , but when I copy the code to a Web Application where I have a Servlet listening to my Android application , when I run the servlet , and the servlet calls the  code of the bot that use Selenium, it throws that error when it comes to that line

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\manue\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

I had read that it can be becouse of the version of guava that I have , but my version of guava is updated , and I dont know why Im getting this error.

In my maven pom.xml I have the dependencies like this

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here there is a screenshot of the structure of my project.
[screenshot of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydaiS.png)

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to a possibly related error message when I removed the Google Collections jar from the lib path.

(Source)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a classpath issue. What version of guava-X.jar do you have in our classpath? (most probably in WEB-INF/lib of webapp). Possible solution is to declare latest version of guava in your pom.xml explicitly. For 3.10.0 of selenium, you need:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>24.0-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Im using guava-23.6-jre, I have tried adding this dependency and it update me to guava 24.0-jre but still dont working.

Comment: I have tried all versions of guava since 24.0-jre to 18.0 and no one works.

Comment: Have you checked that when you change the version in pom, this version is actually put into WEB-INF/lib folder?

Comment: My WEB-INF folder is empty , there is not any lib folder inside. Im going to upload a screenshot of the structure of my project. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydaiS.png

Comment: Yes, it's empty because these are the sources. Once you project is built and is deployed to server (tomcat? - to webapps folder), then it should be most probably packaged as project.war file. It's a zip archive - if you rename it to project.zip and then unpack, you should see a lib folder in the WEB-INF one.

Comment: Manuel - can you please upvote my answer if you find it useful

Comment: Hi alexzender , I have found the folder that you told me , and i have all the libraries in. I keep trying to find where the error is comming but i cant, thank you all in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi Manuel - do you have only one guava jar there or multiple ones?

Comment: I have only one , the guava-24.1-jre.jar. And i have it like you told me , adding the selenium dependency in the pom and the lastest guava version too.