# Not able to create chromeOptions with selenium chrome driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless-browser

I am using selenium chrome driver with version 3.6.0
and using google-guava 23.0. 
When i do this :

```
 ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
```

It gives following error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:329)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
```

I also checked this : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver/3.6.0
Can anyone help me what version of guava should i use here ?

Code :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
    log.warn("chrome driver path is : {}", driverPath);
    List<String> options = proxyConfig.getChromeOptions();
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
      chromeOptions.addArguments(options);
    Map<String, String> capabilites = proxyConfig.getCapabilities();
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : capabilites.entrySet()) {
      chromeOptions.setCapability(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280240/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-google-common-base-preconditions

Comment: what is proxyConfig in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question about your particular usecase why you are trying to signal out **Selenium Client v 3.6.0** and **google-guava 23.0** individually.

To keep it simple,

- **Selenium Client v 3.6.0** uses **guava v23.0**
- Release Notes of [*Selenium Client v 3.5.1*](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases/tag/selenium-3.5.1) clearly mentions the following :

> - Bump guava to version 23.

So, I don't see any issue out there.

However, as an end user instead of selecting individual jars from multiple **selenium-java-X.Y.Z.zip** releases user should consider completely removing all the *Selenium* related **jars** from the older build and replace with the new **jars** from the new build.

### This particular issue

This error message...

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

...implies that the *Java Client* was unable to find `ChromeDriver()`

It will be tough to analyze the real issue in absence of your code trials. However as per [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;) with Selenium, gradle and ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49021707/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-google-common-base-preconditions-checkstatezlj/49022224#49022224) you need to use the `System.setProperty()` line to set the **ChromeDriver** binary path (**not the chrome binary path**). For that you have to download the *ChromeDriver* binary from the [*ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome*](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) and place it in your system and mention the absolute path of the *ChromeDriver* through `System.setProperty()` line. Hence you have to use the line :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
// configurations through chromeOptions 
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions );
```

Comment: i am already setting driver path in my code, please take a look at this.